# Spring web PUT method passing null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working in `Spring MVC` and while submitting `put` method I am getting `null` values in controller.
Code:

```
<form:form action="../${user.id}" method="post" commandName="user">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">First Name</label>
                        <form:input path="name" class="form-control" id="name"
                            placeholder="Full Name" />
                    </div>
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="SAVE">
                </form:form>
```

my put mapping on receiving end

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        userService.updateUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(id));
        return "redirect:/users/" + id;
    }
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I have another from with `post` request, which is working fine but this one is getting null. Please help me solve this

NOTE: Id is still getting value but object `user` is not

Comment: `<form:input path="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" />`

try replacing by this line

Comment: @sunkuet02 But this is the input I am fetching

Comment: @sunkuet02 I am still getting null value even after adding `name` inside form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put mapping

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
```

but your form has POST method

```
<form:form action="../${user.id}" method="post" commandName="user">
```

Comment: even if I change it to put it wont work, I am getting null values

Comment: Getting null values is another issue. Likely related to User object and for control names (should be exactly the same)